# How to find out all keys in a set of maps?

Tags: clojure

If I have a set of maps like this

```
(def a #{
          {:a 1 :b 2}
          {:a 3 :b 4}
          {:b 1 :c 2}
          {:d 1 :e 2}
          {:d 1 :y 2}
})
```

: how can I find out all the keys? so doing :

```
(find-all-keys a)
```

:returns:

```
(:a :b :c :d :e :y)
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
user=> (into #{} (flatten (map keys a)))
#{:y :a :c :b :d :e}
```

Comment: This is broken: flatten is way too aggressive. A simple mapcat will suffice. Consider `(into #{} (flatten (map keys [{[1 2] 0}])))`, which returns `#{1 2}` instead of the correct `#{[1 2]}`.

Comment: yes, I understand this - I always forget about mapcat - I usually use generic list manipulation functions...

Answer (score 11):

Another way:

```
(distinct (mapcat keys a))
```

Answer (score 4):

Almost the same way:

```
(set (mapcat keys a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
(reduce #(into %1 (keys %2))  #{}  a)
```